# How is sockeye salmon available year round?

Tags: food-preservation, salmon

I notice that smoked sockeye salmon is available year round in supermarkets, but the commercial fishing season in Bristol Bay, at least, is only during the summer. If they are only fishing during the summer, how is it that the smoked salmon is available consistently through the year?

Comment: Do they say they are local catch?

Answer (score 4):

1. The smoked salmon is stored frozen and released periodically for retail sale or
2. The fish is stored frozen and then thawed before smoking.

I frequently buy thinly sliced smoked salmon frozen in vacuum packaging.